# Registering a task in a Joomla controller

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I am trying to register a custom task in my controller in Joomla 3.x so I am modifying the constructor (like in 1.5/2.5) with:

```
<?php
 // No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class jjemailControllerjjemail extends JControllerLegacy
 {
/**
 * constructor (registers additional tasks to methods)
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($config = array())
{
    parent::__construct($config);

    // Register Extra tasks
    $this->registerTask('email, 'email');
}

public function email()
{
    $this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_jjemail&view=thanks', $msg);
}
}
```

Now if I add a var dump in the constructor before the task registering then that is showing but adding a var dump into the email() function is giving nothing. So I guess I'm failing at registering the task somewhere.

The route calling this looking like: `JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_jjemail&task=jjemail.email');`

Anyone got any ideas as to why I'm failing in such stupid fashion?

Comment: `$this->registerTask('email, 'email');` is missing a single quote after first "email"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Joomla 1.5 you don't need to register default tasks' names.
You only register aliases to map them to one of controller's methods:

```
$this->registerTask('emailAbc, 'email');
$this->registerTask('unpublish, 'publish');
```

If you cannot stop execution of the app it would suggest you are calling wrong task from your form/link.

Check your form/link whether it contains a proper task like: option=com_jjemail?task=jjemail.email
Joomla will do all job for you, mapping "jjemail.email" to the email method of your controller

Comment: Thanks :) I'll remove my constructor then. I think the form link works ok - as the task in the controller is running perfectly fine in Joomla 2.5.

Comment: this is also true for Joomla 3.1